# How to enable double click event to fotorama slider to make full screen

Tags: fotorama

How to enable double click event to fotorama slider to make full screen, like what we are seeing on right top corner

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jquery events http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ to execute this function

fotorama.requestFullScreen()

remember you should initialize fotorama manually in the header of the api you can see how do it.

**Here is a example for you !**

http://jsfiddle.net/meickol/8dv7k/  how you see is easy! good luck!

**HTML**

```
   <base href="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/i/okonechnikov/">

<!-- Fotorama -->
<div class="fotorama_custom" data-width="700" data-ratio="700/467" data-max-width="100%">
  <img src="1-lo.jpg">
  <img src="2-lo.jpg">
  <img src="9-lo.jpg">
  <img src="6-lo.jpg">
  <img src="5-lo.jpg">
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>

    // 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
var $fotoramaDiv = jQuery('.fotorama_custom').fotorama({
  click:false,
  allowfullscreen:true,
});

    // 2. Get the API object.
    var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');


jQuery('.fotorama').dblclick(function(){
    fotorama.requestFullScreen();

});

</script>
```